# Spring Boot/Thymeleaf Executable Jar, Error resolving template

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

When i start my jar file:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [NEW], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

Templates folder/dir structure

[image]

Template Engine debug detail

[image: call template engine from my code]

Template Path debug detail

[image: path to resources]
Jar

[image: into jar]

POM

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.alf</groupId>
<artifactId>vasja</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I went over the options offered here. I can't understand what the problem is. When I run it through ide, as expected, everything works.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can copy paste the image here with the question instead of giving links.

Comment: You probably forgot to put resources folder into you jar. Open you jar with some archive utility like 7zip and see if your templates are inside

Comment: @JAsgarov, this was checked first. Everything is in place.

Comment: Hm I see... Still the fact that it works in IDE tells us that this is not a configuration problem - we should be looking at how you are producing a jar - are you doing it via a commandline or Spring Boot maven configuration? I would recommend following https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot